# Know when a a webpage inside IFrame (situated in an HTA) has completed loading

Tags: javascript, html, iframe, hta, peoplesoft

I have an HTA, which in turn has an Iframe. We are loading an intranet website. A button in the HTA, when clicked, will automate some task. The first step is to login, wait for the next page to load, then perform next option. The main concern here is to know that the next page has been loaded completely, so that we can initiate the code related to page ?

Can some one shed light on how to achieve this. Just to repeat, IFrame is inside HTA.

Below is my code :

```
<html>
<head>
 <HTA:APPLICATION
     APPLICATIONNAME="HTA"
     SYSMENU="YES"
     NAVIGABLE="YES"
>
    <meta http-equiv="x-ua-compatible" content="ie=11">
    <title>HTA</title>

<script type="text/javascript">
    window.resizeTo(900,700);
</script>

<script type="text/javascript" >

function Start() {
var iframePage = document.getElementById("iframeid").contentDocument;
var userId = iframePage.getElementById("userid");
var passwd = iframePage.getElementById("pwd");
var form = iframePage.getElementById("login");
userId.value='aa';
passwd.value='bb';
form.submit();

var iframePages = document.getElementById("iframeid").contentDocument;
   var targetContent = iframePages.getElementById        ("ptifrmtgtframe").contentDocument;
   var runcntl = targetContent.getElementById("PRCSRUNCNTL_RUN_CNTL_ID");
   runcntl.value='test';

}

function Show() { 
    document.getElementById("iframe").style.display = "block";
}



</script>

</head>
 <body> 
        <form class="form" name="form">

                <input class="links" type="button"  value="Show PIA" onclick="Show();" /> 
                <input class="links" type="button"  value="Login" onclick="Start();" /> 


        </form> 
        <br>
        <div class="iframe" id="iframe" style="display:none">
        <iframe application="no" src="my URL" width="600" height="600" id="iframeid"> 
        </div>

 </body> 
 </html>
```

I want that:

```
var runcntl = targetContent.getElementById("PRCSRUNCNTL_RUN_CNTL_ID");
runcntl.value='test';
```

**Should run, only after the page in the IFrame has loaded properly and completely**, since only then the relevant feilds will be loaded. Or else, this will give error.

PS This is a PeopleSoft site.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a simple example of calling code when the `iframe` has loaded. Check out the `onload` attribute of the `iframe` tag. Maybe you can integrate this into your HTA?

```html
<head>
  <script>
  function frameLoaded() {
    alert('frame loaded!');
  };
  </script>
</head>

<body>
  <iframe id="frame" src="https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTML_element#Frames" onload="frameLoaded(this)" />
</body>
```

Comment: Hi @Robin , actually the IFrame is loaded only once, and then we navigate to different pages from it.  I require something from the Java script side. For Example : 
1) The IFrame loads, and show the login page
2) The button click automatically logs us in.
3) Now, i have to wait untill the next page loads properly, then, fill a text box using another JS function.

Please suggest. :-)

Comment: @PrateekJaiswal If you're going to navigate to a diffrent page, then you actually load more than one page to the iframe, and onload event of the iframe will fire on the main page. Notice, that when the page has been changed, you need to re-assign all the references to the needed objects on the main page, otherwise "Access denied" error occurs.

Comment: Hi @Teemu    , yes i a, navigating to different pages from the main page, have to execute different java script for different pages. Hence , need to stop that JS from executing until the corresponding pages loads completely. Will onload even help me here ? or i will have to use some other approach ?

Comment: @PrateekJaiswal Yes, as long as all the pages has the same domain.

Comment: Hi @Teemu , if above example is considered, frameloaded() will be called just once , after the main page loads? or each and every time,  when  a new page is loaded into the Iframe ?

Comment: @PrateekJaiswal Only once? How is that? The set load event fires every time a new document is fully loaded to the iframe, as long as the document is loaded fromt the same domain.

Answer (score 0):

If you have access to the page, use javascript inter-window communication to trigger the JS you need. The child iframe can tell the parent when to run java script.

From a pure PeopleSoft perspective you can use related action framework component events to do what you like, too, without customization.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can check the code for related content as reference. Such as OpenRCService and onRCService. In PT_COMMON, the showModalDialog method also related to the RC function which have the logic to detect a iframe is loaded.